# Syncing core data to a back end

Tags: core-data, ticoredatasync, ftasync

i am Trying to Sync Core Data with Parse as BackEnd with FTASYNC(https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync), although i am not very comfortable with the solution .
So the Question is if there is any easier solutions for BackEnd Solution Syncing Code , even if it is not with "Parse".

Thank you

Tamer Alaa

Comment: Why are you not comfortable doing it with FTASync?

Comment: FTASync isn't as active as it once was — the maintainer says that [he's really really busy](https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync/issues/9) so it's going to struggle with any changes from the Parse side.

I've personally used it and found it difficult to debug any problems that arise from sync. From its sample project I can see that sync can be very robust — it's just that I don't know how to replicate that level of robustness for my app!

Comment: so Is there is anyway to sync my core data with backend , i have heard that it is easier to be done via stock Mob , although i have not tried it

Comment: What solutions have you guys eventually found?